# Integration Environment Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

When accessing the INT environment I got this error in the page. 
I already enabled all possible features that causes this error, butI got another error.

> SharePoint Foundation Runtime tkau Unexpected
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The server is not
>   operational. at
>   PMI.Emart.Services.UserService.EmartUser.SetUserInfo(String
>   _strUserID) at PMI.Emart.Services.CacheUtility.CacheManager.GetUserInCache(String
>   _userName) at PMI.Emart.Services.SecurityService.AuthenticationService.GetCurrentUser()
>   at PMI.Emart.Home.EmartGeneralMaster.OnInit(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   f4a97381-7ba8-4d6b-a67a-b94ea1b3b5f4

New Error after enabling the features

> An unexpected error has occurred. Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation.  Correlation ID:
>   f4a97381-7ba8-4d6b-a67a-b94ea1b3b5f4

How to fix it? I need help please.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the last previous deployed package in the INT environment.

Comment: @JamesAMohler: this _is_ the author though.